# Form validation not working with vanilla js

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, frontend, backend

I'm trying to do my first form validation with only Vanilla JS.
I have a form, that has two selects in which you have to select your department and depending on this it will allow you to select another location. I made a script for this.

Now, when I relate another script which is formValidation, it doesn't work and I guess I'm doing the form validation well. I'm starting doing it so it only has one validation but it isn't working.

What could be the problem? When i wrote the form validation in the script file, it override the function or the selects so it didn't work. I don't know how to else doing a form validation because I'm new to JS and I'm not allowed to use jquery or anything.

Thanks

Here is the code pen:

https://codepen.io/yomiram/pen/abNMaMy

HTML :

```
<section id="formSection">
    <span class="textForm">Formulario</span>
    <hr>

    <form action="/" id="form" action="GET">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="name" class="input-control" required/>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido" id="lastName" class="input-control" />
          </div>
        
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" id="email" class="input-control" required/>
          </div>
        
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="input-control" style="flex: 6" id="dpto" required>
                <option selected="selected" class="department">Departamento</option>
            </select>
            <select class="input-control" placeholder="Localidad" id="location" style="flex:6" required>
                <option selected="selected" class="department">Localidad</option>
            </select> 
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" id="ci" class="input-control" placeholder="C.I" style="flex:6" required/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="checkbox" name="conditions" id="conditions" required>
            <label for="conditions" id="conditions"> Acepto las bases y condiciones</label><br>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" id="formButton" class="formButton" value="Enviar">
        
          </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

SCRIPT JS (SELECT FUNCTION):

// DISPLAYING DATA IN SELECT

```
var dptosLocs = {
    "Artigas":["Artigas"," Bella Unión"],
    "Canelones":["Canelones"," Santa Lucía"],
    "Montevideo":["Montevideo"],
    "Salto":["Salto"," Daymán"," Arapey"]
};

var sel = document.getElementById('dpto');
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

Object.keys(dptosLocs).forEach(function(dptosLoc, index) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = dptosLoc;
    opt.value = dptosLoc;
    fragment.appendChild(opt);
});

sel.appendChild(fragment);

document.getElementById("dpto").onchange = function() {defineDpto()};

function defineDpto() {
  var dpto = document.getElementById("dpto").value;

  if (dpto == "Artigas" ) {
    var sel = document.getElementById('location');
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  Object.values(dptosLocs["Artigas"]).forEach(function(dptosLoc, index) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = dptosLoc;
    opt.value = dptosLoc;
    fragment.appendChild(opt)

    sel.appendChild(fragment);
}); 

  } else if (dpto == "Canelones") {
      document.getElementById('location').options.length = 0;

      var sel = document.getElementById('location');
      var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    
      Object.values(dptosLocs["Canelones"]).forEach(function(dptosLoc, index) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.innerHTML = dptosLoc;
      opt.value = dptosLoc;
      fragment.appendChild(opt)

      sel.appendChild(fragment);
  });

  } else if (dpto == "Montevideo") {
      document.getElementById('location').options.length = 0;

      var sel = document.getElementById('location');
      var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    
      Object.values(dptosLocs["Montevideo"]).forEach(function(dptosLoc, index) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.innerHTML = dptosLoc;
      opt.value = dptosLoc;
      fragment.appendChild(opt)

      sel.appendChild(fragment);
  });
  } else if (dpto == "Salto") {
      document.getElementById('location').options.length = 0;

      var sel = document.getElementById('location');
      var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    
      Object.values(dptosLocs["Salto"]).forEach(function(dptosLoc, index) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.innerHTML = dptosLoc;
      opt.value = dptosLoc;
      fragment.appendChild(opt)

      sel.appendChild(fragment);
  });
  }
}
```

FORM VALIDATION:

```
function validar (){
  var name, lastName, email, dpto, location, ci, condictions, expresion;

  name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
  email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  dpto = document.getElementById('dpto').value;
  location = document.getElementById('location').value;
  ci = document.getElementById('ci').value;
  conditions = document.getElementById('conditions').value;

  if (name === ""){
    alert("El campo nombre está vacío");
  }
}
```

Comment: You are never calling the `validar` function

Comment: Also, I can see a lot of code repeating itself for the select filling. If you look closely the only difference between the blocks is the `Object.values(dptosLocs["Salto"])` part. You should have just ONE block and do `Object.values(dptosLocs[dpto])` since the dpto is what is changinh

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how it can read the value "Salto" and return the array for Salto precisely

Comment: Basically you're saying, if a = 1 then read array[1], else if a = 2 then read array[2] ... You can just say read array[a]. Let me know if it's unclear, I will post this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your script is that the validar() function is never called.
Please, remember, if you write a function and you never call it in your code, it will never be executed.
What you have to do is to add the call to your validar() function in the onsubmit event of the form.

```
<form action="/" id="form" action="GET" onsubmit="return validar();">
```

And your validar() function should return false if the validation is not verified for the form.

```
if (name === ""){
    alert("El campo nombre está vacío");
    return false;
}
return true;
```

You should take a look at how events are called in javascript when dealing with forms.

Comment: Thanks! Really complete

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the call to the `validar` function

```
<form .... onsubmit="return validar()">
```

Also `validar` should return false if the validation fails and true if it passes